# How I can render fiberhandler API in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, vert.x

I am using a vertx server integrated with swagger. when I am using normal handler its working fine but when I am trying to use fiberhandler its not mapping to correct API in swagger page. Van someone please help in how we can render fiberhandler in vertx to swagger page?

Answer (score 1):

FiberHandler is part of [Vert.x Sync](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-sync), which is now deprecated.

[Vert.x Swagger](https://github.com/phiz71/vertx-swagger) itself (you didn't specify which project you are using, so I'll make some assumptions) wasn't updated in 3 years now.

Your only choice at the moment are:

1. To fork Vert.x Swagger and make changes [around those lines](https://github.com/phiz71/vertx-swagger/blob/master/modules/vertx-swagger-router/src/main/java/com/github/phiz71/vertx/swagger/router/SwaggerRouter.java#L74)
2. Stop using Vert.x Sync, as it's deprecated